# Python Selenium Webdriver - Locating Set of Elements Within Table

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to extract a list of links in a web page using python selenium. All the links on the page have the following format in the source code:

```
<a href = "link"></a>
```

Using the following line gives me all the elements on the page with tag name `a`:

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
```

The issue is that I need only a specific set of links, and all these links are within a table. The above code gives me all the links on the page, even those outside the table. Outline of the page source looks like this:

```
<html>
    ...
    ...
    <frame name = "frame">
        <a href = "unwantedLink">
        <form name = "form">
            <table name = "table">
               <a href = "link1">
               <a href = "link2">
               <a href = "link3">
            </table>
        </form>
    </frame>
    ...
</html>
```

I need `link1`,`link2` and `link3`, but not `unwantedLink`. Both the required links and the unwanted link are in the same frame, so switching frames won't work. Is there a way to look for tag names `a` within the table but not within the parent frame?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you want you want:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table[name='table'] a")
```

The `table[name='table']` bit selects only the table with the attribute `name` set to `"table"`. And then the selector gets all `a` elements that are *descendants* of the table. So it does not matter whether the `a` elements are children of the `table` element or if they appear in side `td` elements.

Note that if you have more than one table that has a `name` attribute set to the value `"table"`, you'll get more elements than you are actually looking for. (There are no guarantees of uniqueness for the `name` attribute.)